# Download a Kaggle dataset using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, kaggle

I would like to download a zipped dataset from Kaggle, using R and rvest package.

I could not figure out how to login to Kaggle website and download the file linked here: https://www.kaggle.com/retailrocket/ecommerce-dataset/downloads/retailrocket-recommender-system-dataset.zip

Other solutions including RCurl and rselenium did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to download Kaggle datasets programatically your best bet is probably to use the API rather than scraping.

- Docs: https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api
- GitHub repo: https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api

It is in Python but you can use it as a command line tool. ([RStudio has a built in terminal you can use to run the commands](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010737148-Using-the-RStudio-Terminal).)